# Pony ORM - Why do I get an assertion error when using the exists command?

Tags: python, caching, ponyorm

I've got a relatively complicated structure and I've been trying to get a minimal working example that breaks but I haven't been able to.

Here is approximately what my table structure is like:

```
class Table1(_db.Entity):                                                       
    name = Required(str)                                                        
    table2s = Set('Table2')                                                     


class Table2(_db.Entity):                                                       
    height = Required(Decimal)                                                  
    length = Required(Decimal)                                                  
    table1 = Optional('Table1')                                                 
    composite_key(height, length, table1)                                       


with db_session:
    Table2(height=2, length=1)
    try:
         Table2.exists(height=2, length=1) # This will throw an error
    except AssertionError:
         Table2.exists(height=2, length=1) # This works
```

In Table2 when I have the equivalent of a `composite_key(height, length)` the code works fine. However, when I have `compmosite_key(height, length, table1)` then when doing the exists statement this returns an `AssertionError`.

I went through some of the source code and have located some of the issues in the following lines:

I'm on version 0.7.6, installed with `pip install pony`

ln 1875: `assert prev_vals != new_vals` in function `db_update_composite_index`

This starts because in line 4151:
`obj = cache_index.get(pkval)` is pulled incorrectly(?).

`obj._dbvals_` doesn't have the entry which is None.

Then in line 4591 if `old_dbval = get_dbval(attr, NOT_LOADED)` old_dbval defaults to NOT_LOADED which leads to an attribute to not be deleted.

This leads to entering the `if statement` loop in line 4616 `if any(attr in avdict for attr in attrs)`

and erroring out on the `cache.db_update_composite_index(obj, attrs, prev_vals, new_vals)` because `prev_vals == new_vals`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like issue reply, not question answer. It was bug in Pony.
We've fixed it [here](https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/commit/e19013d1bb6e9c89eb79477923375a6e6e42f727)
Thanks for reporting.

Comment: Oh sorry do you want me to move this somewhere else or if you post your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: It's okay, but if you meet some bugs next time you could open an issue https://github.com/ponyorm/pony/issues so we can fix it faster

Comment: got it. I assume this will be included in release 0.7.7?

Comment: @evan54 yes it will